# Correct way to write Django post_save signal configuration

Tags: python, django

I've been trying to learn how to use Signals, and unfortunately, my code below doesn't work. In addition, I've come across a dozen posts that all show different ways to do this.

My goal with this post is to clarify and come to a consensus on writing signals in the best way possible in 2019 for scalability. In this example using post_save.

model.py

```
from django.db import models

from metrics.models import InventoryProduct
from product.models.product import Product


class PurchasedOrder(models.Model):
    __quantity_sold = None

    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    purchase_quantity = models.IntegerField()
    quantity_sold = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PurchasedOrder, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__original_quantity_sold = self.quantity_sold

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # If the quantity sold field has changed run the update_sold_out method
        if self.quantity_sold != self.__original_quantity_sold:
            PurchasedOrderLogic.update_sold_out(self)

        super(PurchasedOrder, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__original_quantity_sold = self.quantity_sold

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product.name
```

signals.py:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

from purchasing.models import PurchasedOrder
from purchasing.services.models_logic import PurchasedOrderLogic


@receiver(post_save, sender=PurchasedOrder)
def update_inventory_product_total_qty_purchased(sender, instance):
    PurchasedOrderLogic.update_inventory_product_total_qty_purchased(
        sender, instance.product.id, instance.purchase_quantity
    )
```

This is where my logic resides. When I update the PurchasedOrder purchase_quantity field, it should update also the InventoryProduct's total_qty_purchased field.

purchasing.services.models_logic.py

```
class PurchasedOrderLogic(object):
    @static_method
    def update_inventory_product_total_qty_purchased(purchased_order_class, product_id):
        inventory_product = InventoryProduct.objects.get(pk=product_id)
        total_qty_purchased = purchased_order_class.objects.filter(product_id=product_id).aggregate(
            Sum('purchase_quantity')
        ).get('purchase_quantity__sum')

        inventory_product.total_qty_purchased = total_qty_purchased
        inventory_product.save()
```

apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

from purchasing.models import PurchasedOrder
from purchasing.signals import update_inventory_product_total_qty_purchased


class PurchasingConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'purchasing'
    verbose_name = _('purchasing')

    def ready(self):
        post_save.connect(update_inventory_product_total_qty_purchased, sender=PurchasedOrder)
```

What am missing? I'm not sure even if the signal is running?

I'm triggering .save() by manually modifying any field on the model.

Personally, I've been changing the purchase_quantity field which should print this value as it's called inside the update_inventory_product_total_qty_purchased method

Comment: Exactly how do you "trigger" the `.save()`, some ORM calls like `.update(..)` etc. circumvent the signal. That is why signals are typically not the best option.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I'm triggering .save() by manually modifying any field on the model. So every time I change the purchase_quantity field. It should print this value as it's called inside the update_inventory_product_total_qty_purchased method

Comment: Just to clarify... you have an instance of `PurchaseOrder` (call it `order`), and you are setting `order.purchase_quantity` to a new value?  I assume you are then calling `order.save()`?  Maybe you can include in your question the exact code sequence which you _expect_ to trigger a `post_save` signal?

Comment: @RishiG Let me add the rest of my code for better clarification

Comment: @RishiG Just updated it. You can see that when I update this model, I'm triggering save() on a different modal which field I also want it to update.

Comment: I think you missed the point of my comment, and you still did not include the exact sequence of code which you expect will trigger the `post_save` signal.  My point was: just changing the value of an attribute on a model instance does NOT save the object to the database.  You have to call, for example, `order.save()`.

Comment: @RishiG I see what you mean. I update the field of PurchasedOrder inside the console, and then call a .save() on the instance to save. I put a print('hello') inside the def save() inside my model, and it prints it out. Not sure why the signal is not being triggered.